# How to hide/view result grid in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench on Windows. I execute a query and I get the result. Is there any option or a hotkey to hide/view the result grid without executing the query again and again?

Please help me on this.

Comment: I had this problem (Results Grid would never appear anymore) on macOS 10.14.5 with Workbench 6.3.9.CE. Upgrading to Workbench 8.0.17.CE fixed it.

Answer (score 97):

Here is a simple technique to get back the results grid in MySql WorkBench.
Place the text cursor on a query and use the "EXPLAIN command" for the statement under the cursor.

[image]

That will open the Visual Explain window. In that window you can find Results Grid. Click on that Results Grid.

[image]

You can see the result grid again.

Comment: After the Result Grid was appearing again, I right-clicked on the tab in its lower left that says "Result X", and then selected "Pin Tab".  But it turns out that doesn't help because the results don't refresh when you change and execute the query again, and the Results Grid's refresh icon only refreshes data using the original query.  Oh well, thanks for solution to make it appear!

Comment: Worked for me on Mac 10.12.6, MySQLWorkbench 8.0.12 - thanks!

Comment: Works, but it closes again when you re-run a query, so a restart (or version update) is the only proper solution here.

Comment: I literally just tried this, saw the result grid come back for a half a second and then the whole program shutdown and gave me the "oh gosh, you should report this window" ( macOS v10.15.4, workbench v8.0 )

Comment: works, but it's buggy. But this helped! thanks :)

Answer (score 38):

There's a bug in current latest (8.0.11) MySQL Workbench when for some reason it's no longer showing Results Grid when you execute your statements. The only reasonable way to fix this that I found was to close the app completely and reopen it.

Comment: it also not showing newly created tables until you reload whole thing

Comment: I'm having the same issue with 8.0.12 on my mac and your approach resolve my issue.

Comment: I also have the same issue in 8.0.12 on Windows, sometimes after every query result i must reopen Workbench because it doesnt work

Comment: Fixed in latest version! 8.0.13

Comment: Searching an SO answer before trying a restart … what have I become?! :D

Comment: @panepeter normal! It is a software bug, and requires either a- update workbench app or, b- in my case, update operating system in order to qualify for update to workbench app.  This is a good SO Q&A

Answer (score 9):

You can close result tab this way
[image]

Comment: How to view the result again after closing the tab, without re-executing the query?

Answer (score 8):

I think there is a bug in latest (8.0.11) MySQL Workbench regarding result grid view. Since the installation I was not able to see Result Grid window for any query but I have some how able to get result grid window by changing Resultset Grid font from Tomaha (default with installation) to Consolas 10 and then executing one query.

Hope this might help others facing same issue on 8.0.11 version till the permanent fix.

Comment: This was driving me crazy. I would have to periodically close and reopen app. Changing the font fixed the problem - that is one damned weird display bug.

Comment: Unfortunately just installed the updated and then come across this issue can't believe this hasn't been fixed yet, its a pretty major bug for DB program!!

Answer (score 3):

Updating MySQL workbench worked for me. I'm on MacOSX

Comment: Hi. :) Its been my experience and even reported 8.0.32 workbench crashes on MacOS (ex Monterey v12.6.5). see here https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/724378. Ive had to bump down to 8.0.31 and no problems :)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the best solution, but it is a work-around:

I have MySQL Workbench version 8.0.18 and when I run a query my result grid disappears too. However, I noticed that you can have another tab open (within MySQL Workbench) where the result grid for the same table remains open, and then you can toggle between the two tabs (the query tab and the result grid tab) by using CTRL + TAB and CTRL + SHIFT + TAB.

(Other tab toggle options are here: [How to manage the SQL tabs in MySQL Workbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453439/how-to-manage-the-sql-tabs-in-mysql-workbench))

However, the caveat is that you have to keep refreshing the table's contents in the tab that has the result grid.

(In order to open a new tab you can use CTRL + T, and then click the database and table you wish to view.)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with MySQL Workbench 8.0.19 (Win) and could not get the Result Grid to show whatever I did. I changed the font like some of the other examples but that didn't work. I clicked the EXPLAIN button to see the Execution Plan and that didn't work either. The Result Grid kept going away.

I finally clicked the EXPLAIN button to show the Execution Plan, clicked on the Result Grid icon above that on the right, and then shut down MySQL Workbench hoping it would save the current view settings in a config file or in the registry. That seemed to work. When I opened MySQL Workbench again, the Result Grid appears and I am back to normal.

UPDATE:

I wrote too soon as that didn't have permanence. I did a little more research and found this article in the developer site of MySQL documentation.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-configuring-files.html

So, I decided to shut down MySQL Workbench, rename the 'wb_state.xml' file to 'wb_state-backup.xml' as found in the following path on Windows.

C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench

I then started MySQL Workbench and saw that the 'wb_state.xml' file was created on startup. I then ran a quick SELECT statement to see if I would see the Result Grid and it showed up.

I hope this works for some of you as well!

Comment: Thanks, the `wb_state.xml` seems to be the key here.

Comment: I deleted "wb_options" and it worked for me, the results grid was back. You can delete both and MySQL will recover them. But I think this wasn't the question.