# How to manage the SQL tabs in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

There are multiple SQL queries for every project I need often. My problem is, all my projects need the same MySQL connection in Workbench.

So I have a huge amount of SQL tabs opened all the time, which looks like this:

[image]

Because the amount of tabs exceed the width of my monitor, I have to scroll left and right to get to some queries. The only way to do this is to click on the two arrows (right side on the screenshot). That's really unclear and annoying.

Is there a better way to handle that? Is it possible to quickly switch between multiple SQL tabs or to arrange them in another way?

Answer (score 5):

If you still have many tabs you can switch between them using keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>Page up</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>Page down</kbd>

Comment: Winner... Be nice if scroll wheel worked like in most IDE's

Answer (score 1):

I use these two shortcuts to navigate my long list of open tabs:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd> to jump to the **first** tab, and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>End</kbd> to jump to the **last** tab

**However**, these only work when the input focus in on the list of tabs, not inside the content of the current tab itself. So you will usually have to change the focus by clicking on one of the tabs before using the shortcut. Still annoying, but at least you don't have to scroll through the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use: 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for **next** tab, and  
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for **previous** tab

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best solution would be (don't laugh) not to have so many tabs open. The tabbing interface as GUI element clearly has limitations, especially with many tabs. In MySQL Workbench you can reorder the tabs (drag/drop) and use Ctrl+Tab to switch the tabs of the currently focused tabview.

Better is probably to open the connection multiple times and have only a subset of all queries in each IDE page. Has the additional advantage that you can have a long running query in one IDE and still work in another.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of using one connection for all projects, I created one connection for every project. Now it's much better to handle. Really simple, but I thought there was another solution for that.

Comment: I need to recall my previous comment. It turned out that Workbench doesn't save the tabs for the different connections properly.